# How to check which programs are related to a distribution of a specific repository

Tags: linux, debian, repository

please your help on the following issue.

I understand that the file /etc/apt/sources.list controls repositories from which APT constructs its database. This file contains lines in the following format:

deb location-of-resources distribution component(s)
For example in my system:

deb http://http.kali.org/kali **kali-rolling** main non-free contrib
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ **jessie** main contrib non-free

I want to know which programs on my system are related to the Linux distribution **jessie**, is there any command line or any other way to do so?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Take a look at [Kalli Linux Official Documentation](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aptitude to search which packages are installed from which repo:

```
foo@test:~$ aptitude search "?origin (opensuse) ?installed"
i A libowncloudsync0                                               - the ownCloud sync library                                                
i A libqt5keychain1                                                - Cross platform password store library                                    
i   owncloud-client                                                - The ownCloud sync client - github.com/owncloud/client                    
i A owncloud-client-l10n                                           - Internationalization files for ownCloud
```

so for your example you can try: `aptitude search "?origin (jessie) ?installed"`

Comment: I tried the command with my arguments, it runs prompting no error, in fact, prompting nothing on terminal-command. I tried it with **kali-rolling** and nothing too. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure you have any packages installed from kali-rolling? can you explicitly install a package provided by that repo and then try again?